# fgets() not working.in C?

Tags: c, fgets

Edit: Deleted all but the main question.

My program here is supposed to create a file at a specified directory, and write specified text to it. A correct file's path and content should look something like this:

```
Path: D:\test.txt
Content: The printing succeeded.
```

For some reason, my code won't recognize the "path" variable. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. The "text" variable works fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

//Declaring variables
char path[999];
char text[999];
FILE *fp;

//prompting for path variable
printf("Specify a file path.\n");
fgets(path,999,stdin);
printf(path);

//prompting for the text variable.
printf("What do you want to write?");
fgets(text,999,stdin);
printf(text);

//opening and printing to file.
//fp = fopen("D:\\test.txt", "w");
fp = fopen(path, "w");
fprintf(fp, text);
fclose(fp);

//test print to see that the program completed correctly.
printf("\nThe printing has been done.");
return 0;
}
```

The thing I don't understand is that `fp = fopen("D:\\test.txt", "w");` works, but `fp = fopen(path, "w");` doesn't. I've tried putting in these different paths.:

```
D:\\test.txt
D:\test.txt
D\test.txt
D\\test.txt
```

Comment: **Always** check the result of functions which might encounter an error. If `fopen` fails, you invoke _undefined behaviour_ (just search for this term).

Comment: Wow that's a lot of questions. I know you've got a lot you want answers to, but asking so many at the same time makes giving a coherent answer really difficult! As a general rule, try to limit your questions to a single subject, rather than an entire topic like this one, which is basically "how does C work?" You may find that people will only answer the "main" question and ignore the rest, because they are all answers that can be found in most C tutorials.

Comment: "What are some of the most useful header files?" srsly? how about "those that you actually need"?

Comment: also, files do not behave. and as @IStanley said: read some tutorials…

Comment: @IStanley Okay, thanks. I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I didn't know about that. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't open the file when you open the variable `path` because `fgets()` reads the `newline` and puts it at the end of the string (if there's enough space in the buffer). In order to make it work you have to manually remove the `newline` from the string.

Try this before opening the file.

```
  if(isspace(path[strlen(path)-1]))
             path[strlen(path)-1]='\0';
```

You might also need to include  `<ctype.h>`

Comment: You should test if `path` is not an empty string too.

Comment: See also [Do not assume that fgets() or fgetws() returns a nonempty string when successful](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO37-C.+Do+not+assume+that+fgets()+or+fgetws()+returns+a+nonempty+string+when+successful)

Comment: In corner cases, `path[0]` is the null character and then `path[strlen(path)-1]` is undefined behavior.  Robust solutions at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359

Comment: Thanks @matts & @olaf! I didn't know that fgets read the newline.

Comment: @EmeraldSpire: There is enough information on that behavoir on stack overflow and elsewhere to be found. Also there is documentation for every standard libray function in the C [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). Furthermore, your IDE and/or OS should provide such (on Linux see the man-pages). I'd recommend to first do some research on your own first.

Comment: @olaf my IDE doesn't have a C documentation (At least one that I'm aware of.)